# How to change the time format of a digital clock with a button click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a digital clock which I am displaying through images from 0.png to 9.png. The digital clock is getting displayed properly but the problem is its time format is in 24 hour.

I have tried to change the format of the clock to 12h but it still displays the clock in 24h. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
NSDate *dateShow= [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    //[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    /
    //NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateShow];


    NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents * components =
    [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger firstHourDigit = hour/10;
    NSInteger secondHourDigit = hour%10;
    NSInteger firstMinuteDigit = minute/10;
    NSInteger secondMinuteDigit = minute%10;

    int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
         {

             if(i==0)
                res = firstHourDigit;
         else if(i==1)
                 res = secondHourDigit;
            else if (i==2)
                 res = firstMinuteDigit;
             else 
                 res = secondMinuteDigit;

                 switch (res) {

                     case 0:
                     str_imageName=@"0.png";
                     break;
                     case 1:
                     str_imageName=@"1.png";
                     break;
                    case 2:
                     str_imageName=@"2.png";
                     break;
                     case 3:
                     str_imageName=@"3.png";
                     break;
                    case 4:
                    str_imageName=@"4.png";
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    str_imageName=@"5.png";
                    break;
                    case 6:
                     str_imageName=@"6.png";
                    break;
                    case 7:
                    str_imageName=@"7.png";
                    break;
                    case 8:
                    str_imageName=@"8.png";
                    break;
                    case 9:
                    str_imageName=@"9.png";
                     break;

                    default:
                    break;
                }
            if(i==0)
                [minfirstImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else if(i==1)
                [minsecondImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else if (i==2)
                [secfirstImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else 
                [secSecondImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];



        }
```

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Comment: Please include some code. How are you determining the time and displaying the numbers on your clock? There is nothing here that anyone can help you with.

Comment: @DanielA.White i have added the code .Please check

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` defaults to the preferred date time set in settings. You may need to subtract 12 from all times >= 13 and use `HH` to format hour.

Comment: ...hmmm OR use mod operator...see my example.

Comment: This is rather too broad for Stack Overflow, and seems to be left in an unanswered state. I therefore suggest this question is put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Use a modulo on your hour...

```
value % 12
```

So 9 % 12 = 9, 14 % 12 = 2.... etc

Comment: but i am having a doubt becuase i am having a button which on clicking 24h should show the digital clock in 24h format and the same bttton when clicked in 12h format the digital view should appear in 12h format.

Comment: You need a flag that states whether you want 12 hour or 24 hour... something like BOOL twentyFourHour; then set this on your button clicks. Then where you set your hour value do... hourValue = twentyFourHour ? hourValue : hourValue % 12;

Comment: i am not getting u properly because in my code i am using calendar components and adding it to an integer variable.and then performing calculations on that integer variable.So i am bit confused on how to do

Comment: NSInteger hour = twentyFourHour ? [components hour] : [components hour] % 12; This will give you EITHER 1 - 12 for the hour value OR 1 - 24.

Comment: if you set twentyFourHour to FALSE it will return 12 hour.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4360/discussion-between-simon-lee-and-rani)

Comment: @Joe ya my digital clock is displaying as 0.00 at noon.

Comment: @Rani I thought you said that is what you wanted last time you responded.