# how to make a digital clock display in 12 hour format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have created a digital clock with images from 0.png to 9.png. this clock is working properly.the default time format the  clock shows is in 24format . i want that the clock should display time in format 12hour. i have done the following code but the problem is it always show time in 24hour format:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //timer to recursively call the showClock method.
    twentyfourhour = YES;
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  
    [super viewDidLoad];
}



-(void)showClock
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents * components =
    [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    if (twentyfourhour == YES) {
        twentyfourhour = [components hour]%12;
        int hour = twentyfourhour ? [components hour] : [components hour] % 12;
        NSLog(@"%d",hour);  
        NSInteger minute = [components minute];
        NSInteger firstHourDigit = hour/12;
        NSInteger secondHourDigit = hour%10;
        NSInteger firstMinuteDigit = minute/10;
        NSInteger secondMinuteDigit = minute%10;

        int res=0;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {

            if(i==0)
                res = firstHourDigit;
            else if(i==1)
                res = secondHourDigit;
            else if (i==2)
                res = firstMinuteDigit;
            else 
                res = secondMinuteDigit;

            switch (res) {

                case 0:
                    str_imageName=@"0.png";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    str_imageName=@"1.png";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    str_imageName=@"2.png";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    str_imageName=@"3.png";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    str_imageName=@"4.png";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    str_imageName=@"5.png";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    str_imageName=@"6.png";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    str_imageName=@"7.png";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    str_imageName=@"8.png";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    str_imageName=@"9.png";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            if(i==0)
                [minfirstImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else if(i==1)
                [minsecondImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else if (i==2)
                [secfirstImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else 
                [secSecondImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
        }
    }
    else
    {


    int hour1 = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger firstHourDigit = hour1/10;
    NSInteger secondHourDigit = hour1%10;
    NSInteger firstMinuteDigit = minute/10;
    NSInteger secondMinuteDigit = minute%10;

    int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
         {

             if(i==0)
                res = firstHourDigit;
         else if(i==1)
                 res = secondHourDigit;
            else if (i==2)
                 res = firstMinuteDigit;
             else 
                 res = secondMinuteDigit;

                 switch (res) {

                     case 0:
                     str_imageName=@"0.png";
                     break;
                     case 1:
                     str_imageName=@"1.png";
                     break;
                    case 2:
                     str_imageName=@"2.png";
                     break;
                     case 3:
                     str_imageName=@"3.png";
                     break;
                    case 4:
                    str_imageName=@"4.png";
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    str_imageName=@"5.png";
                    break;
                    case 6:
                     str_imageName=@"6.png";
                    break;
                    case 7:
                    str_imageName=@"7.png";
                    break;
                    case 8:
                    str_imageName=@"8.png";
                    break;
                    case 9:
                    str_imageName=@"9.png";
                     break;

                    default:
                    break;
                }
            if(i==0)
            [minfirstImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else if(i==1)
                [minsecondImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else if (i==2)
                [secfirstImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];
            else 
                [secSecondImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str_imageName]];


         }  

    }


}
```

Comment: Duplicate [of this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807355/how-to-change-the-time-format-of-a-digital-clock-with-a-button-click/7807497#7807497

Comment: Ok, I don't know objective-C, but it looks like you've reversed the 'twentyfourhour' flag such that when 24H is YES you show it in 12 hour format.

Comment: @DavidWinant i don't understand what u r saying

Comment: Have you written all this yourself? Or has it been a helping hand within other peoples code, not accusing just curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//timer to recursively call the showClock method.
twentyfourhour = YES;
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(showClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Would the fact that it say at the top, twentyfourhour = YES, have anything to do with it? Maybe change that to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: if i change the BOOL variable twentyfourhour to NO then also the time format is displayed in 24hour.

Comment: calculation part i searched from the net

Comment: Please help me in where i am going by default why it is displaying time in 24hour format when i set my variable to NO

Answer (score 0):

I can see one place where it might affect your logic.

```
twentyfourhour = [components hour]%12;
```

You will get a non-zero value whenever 'hour' is not multiples of 12, So 9 hours will result in 9 and 15 hours will result in 3. As they are not Zero, your twerntyfourhour will get treated as YES with those assignments.

I hope this might help you in trouble shooting further.